# The limit of a sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to compute this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1^2}+\frac{n}{n^2+2^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2+n^2}\right)$$

Please give me some hint.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879611/how-do-you-calculate-this-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frackn2k

Answer (score 31):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{1\le r\le n}\frac{n}{n^2+r^2} &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{1\le r\le n}\frac1{1+\left(\frac rn\right)^2}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\end{align}$$

$$\text{as }\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Comment: Very elegant method. Thank you!

Comment: @Barbara, my pleasure. Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465075/find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits2n-r-1-fracr-sq. I'm really eager to about the alternatively methods, if any.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee. You provided, for sure, the best and simplest solution to the problem. What amazed me was to have a look to the sum up to $n$. What I got (using a CAS) is $$\frac{-i n \left(H_{(1-i) n}-H_{(1+i) n}\right)+\pi  n \coth (\pi  n)-1}{2 n}$$ which goes to the limit you gave (fortunately for me !). Cheers.

Comment: Wow, that is a beautiful formulae. At first it made no sense to me. But the more I look at it, the more 'obvious' it seems. $\sum_{r=1}^n$ basically adds all points from $r=1$ to $n$. But
 $f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)$ divides $r$ by $n$. Which means the highest value is $1$. When $\lim_{n \to\infty}$ is applied, two things will happen: 1) Ratio $\frac{r}n$ approaches $0$. 2) Infinitesimal increment of the ratio at every step. But what is the other way to describe the summation of infinite no. of points from 0 to 1 of a function?$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Can you please provide a general rigourous proof of this formula as a link or in some reference book and also its general form ?

Comment: @RaghavSingal, See http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-definite-integral/definite-integral-as-limit-of-a-sum/

Comment: @RaghavSingal, Can you google please?

Comment: @RaghavSingal, See  http://people.math.sc.edu/sharpley/math554_s96/554_9/ 
  OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137518/proof-for-the-riemann-integral-in-terms-of-riemann-sums-using-the-epsilon-delta