# How to solve this: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{2n+3k}{n} \right)^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to solve this:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{2n+3k}{n} \right)^2$$

The answer is supposed to be 39.

My attempt:

$$\frac{3}{n}\sum\left(4+\frac{12}{n}k+\frac{9}{n^{2}}k^{2}\right)=\frac{3}{n}\left(4+\frac{12}{n}\sum k+\frac{9}{n^{2}}\sum k^{2}\right)=\frac{3}{n}\left(4+\frac{12}{n}\frac{n}{2}\left(n+1\right)+\frac{9}{n^{2}}\frac{n}{6}\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)\right)=3\left(6+3\right)=27\neq39$$

Comment: $\sum 4 \neq 4$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks! $\sum 4 = 4n => 3 (4 + 6 + 3) = 39$.

Comment: You got it ! With respect to your comment to lab's answer, you made a mistake developing $(2+3x)^2$. And you are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac3n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2+3\frac kn\right)^2$$

$$=3\int_0^1(2+3x)^2\ dx$$

$$\text{as }\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Comment: $3\int (4+6x+9x^2) = 3 (4x+3x^2+3x^3) = 3 (4+3+3) = 30 \neq 39$

Comment: @Yaldc, See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2

Comment: $$3\int (4+12x+9x^2) = 3 (4x+6x^2+3x^3) = 3 (4+6+3) = 39$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, There was a typo, it should be : $$3\int_0^1 (2+3x)^2\ dx=\frac{(2+3x)^3|_0^1}3=\frac{5^3-2^3}3 $$