# How do you calculate this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2+k^2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, riemann-sum

How to find the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}S(n)$, where $S(n)$ is given by $$S(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{k}{n^2+k^2}$$

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn-%3E+infinity%7D+%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D+%28k%29%2F%28n%5E2%2Bk%5E2%29) is unable to calculate it.

This is a question from a questions booklet, and the options for the answer are--

$\begin{align}
&A) \dfrac{\pi}{2} \\
&B) \log 2 \\
&C) \dfrac{\pi}{4} \\
&D) \dfrac{1}{2} \log 2
\end{align}$

Comment: Hint: $S(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(k/n)}{1+(k/n)^2}.$ Think about Riemann sums.

Comment: @RagibZaman We haven't yet been taught Riemann sums.

Comment: @Pkwssis he means turn it into an integral.

Comment: @ozo We haven't been taught that either, as of yet.

Comment: @DanielFischer No..it is k..

Comment: This seems to be the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879611/how-do-you-calculate-this-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frackn2k

Comment: I apologize - it is not the same question, only similar.

Comment: @egreg how is that a duplicate? The target is about sum_k **n**  /(n^2+k^2) not k/(n^2+k^2). (I ping you as I think you are the only pingable closer.) I reopened. If I miss something let me know and I'll undo.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Clearly, 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2+k^2} &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\frac{k}{n}}{1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}}
\stackrel{\text{Riemann sum}}\longrightarrow \int_0^1 \frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2}=\left.\frac{1}{2}\log (1+x^2)\right|_0^1\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\log 2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 9):

You could get away with a simple estimate of the expected range of the limit:

With $S_1(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2+n^2}$ and $S_2(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2}$, we have
$$S_1(n)<S(n)<S_2(n)$$
The limits for $S_1$ and $S_2$ are
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_1(n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2n^2}\frac{n^2-n}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_2(n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nk=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{n^2-n}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
So we know that 
$$\frac{1}{4}<\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S(n)<\frac{1}{2}.$$
Out of the given answers, that leaves only $\frac{1}{2}\log2$.

Comment: Also saw this before checking with the Reimann sum approach. Good example of where multiple choice rewards estimation rather than just going by the book.

Answer (score 2):

The general term is equivalent to $\frac{1}{k}$, so I don't think this converges at all.

Comment: Note: The sum's upper limit has been corrected from $\infty$ to $n$ by the original poster.