# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1} ^n\frac{1}{n+i}=\ln2 $

Tags: limits, summation

Need help with the following proof. 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1} ^n\frac{1}{n+i}=\ln2 $$

Its the night before my maths exam. I know its a silly question but I need to prove whether given equality is true or false. With reason.

Comment: [Refer This for $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 4):

Like [The limit of a sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2),

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{n+r}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{1+r/n}$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}$$

Comment: Note: $$=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}=\ln2$$

Comment: @DigitalBrain, I have left it for JoshBoiskin to finish off

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here that has caused the down-vote

Comment: I didn't downvote

Comment: @Unnamed, I was requesting the down-voter to point out the mistake, so I could learn