# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty} \bigg(\frac{(2n!)}{n!^2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{4n}}$

Tags: limits

I am trying to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \bigg(\frac{(2n!)}{n!^2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{4n}},$$ which came from trying to find the radius of convergence of the complex power series $$\sum_{n\ge0} z^{2n}\frac{\sqrt{(2n)!}}{n!}$$ In the limit I we have some cancellation: $$\frac{(2n!)}{n!^2}=\frac{1\cdots n\cdot (n+1)\cdots(2n)}{1\cdots n\cdot 1\cdots n}=\frac{(n+1)\cdot(2n)}{1\cdots n},\,\,\,(*)$$
and the right hand side is less than $2^n$, so an upper bound on the limit is $$(2^n)^{\frac{1}{4n}}=2^{1/4}$$
The right hand side of $(*)$ is at least $1$, so I have the bounds $1,2^{1/4}$, but I don't know how to get a better estimate. How can I compute this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$A=\lim_{n\to \infty} \bigg(\frac{(2n!)}{n!^2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{4n}}$$

$$\implies\ln A=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1{4n}\sum_{r=1}^n\ln\frac{n+r}r$$

$$\implies4\ln A=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\ln\frac{1+r/n}{r/n}$$

the rest should be like [The limit of a sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2)

Comment: how do you jump from the 3rd line to the blue line?

Comment: @TheSubstitute, Have you noticed the last line of the other answer ? 
 $$\text{as }\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> With Stirling Asymptotic formula:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}
\bracks{\pars{2n}! \over \pars{n!}^{2}}^{1/\pars{4n}}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}
\bracks{\root{2\pi}\pars{2n}^{2n + 1/2}\expo{-2n}\over
\pars{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n}}^{2}}^{1/\pars{4n}}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{%
\pars{2\pi}^{-1/2}2^{2n + 1/2}n^{n}}^{1/\pars{4n}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{\pars{2\pi}^{-1/\pars{8n}}\ 
2^{1/2 + 1/\pars{8n}}\ n^{-1/\pars{8n}}}
=2^{1/2}
\\[5mm]&= \color{#66f}{\Large\root{2}} \approx {\tt 1.4142}\quad\mbox{since}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\pars{2\pi}^{-1/\pars{8n}} & = & 1
\\[2mm]
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}2^{1/2 + 1/\pars{8n}} & = & 2^{1/2} = \root{2}
\\[2mm]
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}n^{-1/\pars{8n}} & = & 1
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}