# Limit of a certain quotient

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} {\sum_{k=1}^n {1\over\sqrt{k}}\over\sqrt{n}} $$

I understand that the summation is *divergent* and this is $\infty\over\infty$ form. But how to proceed further??

Comment: Are you familiar with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem ?

Comment: $$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k/n}}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: You may miss $1/n$ in front of the sum.

Comment: @mathlove, Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Stolz-Cesaro theorem (which is pretty useful) we get:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} {\sum_{k=1}^n {1\over\sqrt{k}}\over\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=2$

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for posting this answer , I learned a new theorem today.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt k}}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac kn}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\ dx=2.$$

Comment: @mathlove, that is not always true for improper integrals. We can find a positive unbounded $f$ on $(0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1f$  converges (in the improper Riemann integral sense), yet $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{n=1}^{k}f(\frac kn)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @zhw.: You are right. Thank you for pointing it out. I deleted my misleading comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use the the inequalities:
$$ \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt n} \leq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}=\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}$$

and as a consequence:
$$2\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-1}{\sqrt n}\leq {\sum_{k=1}^n {1\over\sqrt{k}}\over\sqrt{n}}\leq 2$$

and the limit is $2$

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw this solution in the mix: Let $S_n$ be the sum in the numerator. Using crayons and rectangles, we see$$\int_1^n \frac{dx}{\sqrt x} < S_n < 1+ \int_1^n \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}.$$The integral equals $2\sqrt n - 2.$ Divide by $\sqrt n$ and the limit of $2$ follow easily.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use L'Hopital's rule. So the limit becomes

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2 \sqrt{n} }{\sqrt{n}} =2.$$

Comment: Eh? What are the numerator, denominator in the quotient of differentiable functions?

Comment: Can you explain?