# Let a be a positive number. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}[\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{2a+n}+\cdots +\frac{1}{na+n}]$

Tags: calculus, limits

Problem :

Let $a$ be a positive number. Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{a+n}+\frac{1}{2a+n}+\cdots +\frac{1}{na+n}\right]$$

Please suggest how to proceed in such limit problems, will be of great help thanks.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2

Answer (score 7):

We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{ka+n} = \dfrac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{1+a\cdot \dfrac{k}n} \sim \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{1+ax} = \dfrac{\log(1+a)}a$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over a + n} + {1 \over 2a + n} + \cdots +
{1 \over na + n}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over ka + n} =
{1 \over a}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1 + n/a}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over a}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over k + 1 + n/a} - {1 \over k + n + 1 + n/a}}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over a}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{H_{n + n/a} - H_{n/a}}\qquad
\pars{~H_{z}:\ Harmonic\ Number~}
\end{align}

> [Since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation)
>   $\ds{H_{z} \sim \ln\pars{z} + \gamma + {1 \over 2z}\ \mbox{as}\ \verts{z} \to \infty\ \mbox{with}\ \,\verts{\mrm{arg}\pars{z}} < \pi}$ where $\ds{\gamma}$ is the *Euler-Mascheroni Constant*:

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over a + n} + {1 \over 2a + n} + \cdots +
{1 \over na + n}} =
{1 \over a}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln\pars{n + n/a \over n/a} =
\bbx{\ln\pars{1 + a} \over a}
\end{align}