# Turning infinite sum into integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Could someone explain how one can replace infinite sum with integral?

Examples (or you may use your own, it doesn't matter as I want to understand principles):

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin \frac{i-1}{n} \pi$$

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{1 + \frac{i}{n}}$$

I see that $\frac{1}{n}$ denote partition, so my problem is that I don't know how to figure out the function, hence, the integrand.

Comment: Are you looking for something like $\dfrac{\displaystyle \int_{x=0}^{\pi} \sin(x)\, dx }{ \displaystyle \int_{x=0}^{\pi}\,  dx}$ and $\dfrac{\displaystyle \int_{x=0}^{1} \sqrt{1+x} \, dx }{ \displaystyle \int_{x=0}^{1} \, dx}$  so in effect finding the mean of the summands or integrand? Or do you want bounds?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2

Comment: These are not infinite sums. If one finds $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_n$, that can be considered an infinite sum. But $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n a_n$ is somewhat different from that. Notice that if you push the $1/n$ inside the sum, getting $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_n} n$, then as $n$ increases, one isn't just adding more terms, but actually changing the terms that were already there by dividing them by a larger value of $n$. In $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a_n$, increasing $n$ merely adds more terms.

Comment: Bravo, @MichaelHardy, you explained well what I tried to say much more briefly in my answer.

Comment: @RoryDaulton : Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Left-hand Rectangular Approximation Method (LRAM) says that, if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$,

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f\left(a+\frac{b-a}n (i-1) \right)$$

Comparing that with your first sum, we see that $\ a=0,\ b=\pi, f(x)=\sin x/\pi$. So, *the limit of your sum as $n\to\infty$* is

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \sin x\,dx$$

Note that this is not your sum, as you asked, not even an infinite sum, but a limit of sums.

The Right-hand Rectangular Approximation Method (RRAM) says that, if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$,

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f\left(a+\frac{b-a}n i \right)$$

Comparing that with your second sum, we see that $f(x)=\sqrt x,\ a=1,\ b=2$. So 
*the limit of your sum as $n\to\infty$* is

$$\int_1^2 \sqrt x\,dx$$

Note: The main difference in these two methods is that LRAM has the term $f(a)$ but not the term $f(b)$ while RRAM has the term $f(b)$ but not the term $f(a)$ in the sum. This is due to the different indices on the sum.

Comment: Thank you! Very clear explanation!

Comment: @push: Thanks, I try, especially in my calculus class. Do take note of what MichaelHardy wrote in his comment.

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea is this:

If $f$ is a positive increasing function
then
$f(n)
\le \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx
\le f(n+1)
$.

Similarly,
if $f$ is a positive decreasing function
then
$f(n)
\ge \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx
\ge f(n+1)
$.

For increasing $f$,
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(i)
\le \int_0^{n} f(x) dx
\le \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(i+1)
$
or
$\sum_{i=0}^{n} f(i)-f(n)
\le \int_0^{n} f(x) dx
\le \sum_{i=0}^{n} f(i)-f(0)
$
or
$f(0)
\le \sum_{i=0}^{n} f(i)-\int_0^{n} f(x) dx
\le f(n)
$.

For a decreasing function,
the inequalities are reversed.

From this you can show that
for a bounded piecewise monotonic function,
the sum converges to the integral.