# Compute the next limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{1}{\frac{i}{n}+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus

Compute the next limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{1}{\frac{i}{n}+1}\right)$$

I have this

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{1}{\frac{i}{n}+1}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{\frac{ni}{n}+n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{i+n}\right)$$

If I use the integral criteria can I get some thing?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Consider 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{\frac{i}{n}+1}\right)\frac{1}{n}$$
as a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) related to the integral 
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x+1} dx.$$