# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} ( \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+ \frac{1}{(2n)^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} ( \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+ \frac{1}{(2n)^2})$

Please help me find this limit .

I cannot use cauchys limit theorem on this problem . So I am stuck and clueless

Comment: Nothing ..They are just giving additional information.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k + n}^{2}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{{1 \over n}
\bracks{{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k/n + 1}^{2}}}}
\end{align}
Note that $\ds{{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k/n + 1}^{2}}}$ is a convergent Riemann sum $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{as}\ n \to \infty~}}$ such that the above limit $\underline{\mbox{vanishes out}}$.

Comment: @AbhishekChandra You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that

$$0 < \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\dots+ \frac{1}{(2n)^2} < n\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}.$$

Since the limit of the right side is $0,$ the squeeze theorem shows our limit is $0.$

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. It follows that $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty}\sum\limits_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=0$.

Notice that $0\leq \sum\limits_{n=m+1}^{2m}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq \sum\limits_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$. Now just use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Can you give me a solution without sandwich theorem

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with sandwich theorem..A solution with Cauchy's theorem will be helpful

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/limits-from-equations-ab/squeeze-theorem-ab/v/squeeze-sandwich-theorem you can learn about it here, it is quite useful.

Comment: Thanks for that..But just for my interest can it be solvable by other method that will be very kind of you

Answer (score 1):

For $j\in \mathbb N$ and $x\in (j,j+1)$ we have $\frac {1}{(j+1)^2}<\frac {1}{x^2}$.  Therefore $$0<\sum_{j=n}^{2n-1}\frac {1}{(j+1)^2}=\sum_{j=n}^{2n-1}\int_j^{j+1}\frac {1}{(j+1)^2}dx<\sum_{j=n}^{2n-1}\int_j^{j+1}
\frac {1}{x^2}dx=$$ $$=\int_n^{2n}\frac {1}{x^2}dx=\frac {1}{n}- \frac {1}{2n}=\frac {1}{2n}.$$