# Find $\lim_{ n \to \infty }\left( (\frac{1}{n})^{17}+(\frac{2}{n})^{17}+(\frac{3}{n})^{17}+...+(\frac{n}{n})^{17} \right) =?$

Tags: limits

Find the limit :

$$\lim_{ n \to \infty }\left(  (\frac{1}{n})^{17}+(\frac{2}{n})^{17}+(\frac{3}{n})^{17}+...+(\frac{n}{n})^{17} \right) =?$$

My Try:

$$\lim_{ n \to \infty } (\frac{1}{n})^{17}=(\frac{2}{n})^{17}=(\frac{3}{n})^{17}=...=(\frac{k}{n})^{17}=0\\\lim_{ n \to \infty } (\frac{n}{n})^{17}=1$$

so :
$$\lim_{ n \to \infty }\left(  (\frac{1}{n})^{17}+(\frac{2}{n})^{17}+(\frac{3}{n})^{17}+...+(\frac{n}{n})^{17} \right) =1$$

is it right ?

Comment: Your approach is not correct, When you sum together many things which tend to 0 their sum can be very large. For $n=5$ the sum is $1.02$, and at $n=400$ the sum is $22.7$

Answer (score 9):

Like [The limit of a sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2/469886#469886).

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\dfrac rn\right)^{17}=\int_0^1x^{17}dx$$

Comment: Um...Where does the $\frac{1}{n}$ come from? It isn't in the question.

Comment: @S.C.B., We can write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\dfrac rn\right)^{17} $$ as $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\left(\dfrac rn\right)^{17} $$ is finite

Comment: Note $\lim_{n \to \infty}n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @S.C.B.: It proves the sum approaches infinity.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Sorry for the edit. I cannot seem to reverse it. Please ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k \over n}^{17} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n^{17}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{17}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{n + 1}^{17} \over \pars{n + 1}^{17} - n^{17}} = \bbx{\ds{\infty}}
\end{align}

> Note that the numerator is a $17$-degree polynomial while the Denominator is a $16$-degree one !!!.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the sum as $s_n$, then given any $M > 0$, we have there exists large enough $m > 0$ such that,
$$
s_k > M,\quad k \ge m
$$

For example, $m = \Big{\lceil}2M/(1 - \frac{1}{2^{1/17}})\Big{\rceil}$ (let $m_1=\Big{\lceil}\frac{m}{2^\frac{1}{17}}\Big{\rceil}$, clearly $\big{(}\frac{m_1}{m}\big{)}^{17} \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $m - m_1 > 2M$, hence $s_m > \frac{1}{2}\cdot(2M)=M$).

Therefore, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}s_n=\infty$. (Definition 3.3 in http://math.mit.edu/~apm/ch03.pdf)

BTW, @labbhattacharjee, (Sorry I can not make a comment on your answer directly), I have some doubts about some arguments in the answer. I think we can only get

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(n)g(n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n)\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}g(n)
$$

when both $g(n)$ and $f(n)$ have finite limit.

For example,

$$
1 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{n + 1} \neq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n+1} = \infty\cdot 0
$$