# Evaluation of the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac k{k^2+n^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, infinity

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac k{k^2+n^2}$$

I need to evaluate this limit, but I don't know how to start. Should i take $1/n^2$ out? 
Help required. Thank you.

Comment: How do you take $\frac{1}{n^2}$ out?

Comment: it is a Riemann sum

Comment: We haven't studied Riemann sums yet, so how can I evaluate it?

Comment: @AgnesVanWood The two current answers rely on Riemann sums. If you haven't studied them, please include in your question where this expercise came from (e.g., chapter on XYZ), and what techniques you know/are expected to use (probably this very same XYZ). Otherwise, you are likely to get answers that you don't yet know how to use or reproduce.

Comment: @ClementC. Okay, thank you.

Comment: @AgnesVanWood, See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2/469886#469886

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, factor out $1/n^2$. This leaves you with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\frac{(k/n)}{1+(k/n)^2}.$$ This resembles a Riemann sum. Under good conditions, we have $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b-a}{n}f\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right).$$ From this, we conclude that $a=0$, $b=1$, and $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$, so we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{k^2+n^2}=\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Rewrite
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac k{k^2+n^2}
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{\frac{k^2}{n}+n}
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\frac{k}{n}}{\frac{k^2}{n^2}+1}
$$
and recognize a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx$, where $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}.
$$
(This is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, since continuous.)

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. For the sake of verification, the final limit will be $\int_0^1 f = \frac{\ln 2}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I've already calculated the final limit and got the same answer. Again, thank you. It was really helpful and incredibly fast answer!