# Convergence of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n+k}{(n^2+k^2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show convergence of : $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n+k}{(n^2+k^2)}$$

Comment: Hi. Tried helping with the typesetting, please let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Use the idea of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2/469886#469886

Comment: Maybe there should be a limit $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Thank you,I'll try solving it that way,the problem asks me to prove that this series converges

Comment: Do you mean the series with general term this sum, or the sequence defined by this sum?

Comment: Indeed, **which series?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will try to evaluate it using limit of a sum which will eventually prove that it converges.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n+k)\frac{1}{n^2}}{(n^2+k^2)\frac{1}{n^2}}$$ 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(1+\frac{k}{n})\frac{1}{n}}{(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2})}$$ 
Converting it into a definite integral. 
$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{1+x}{1+x^2} dx$$
$$\int_{0}^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right) dx$$
This can be easily evaluated.

The result comes out to be $\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2}ln2$

Which proves that it the given sum converges.