# sum of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

I am trying to figure out how to represent the integral [from 0 to 1] of cos(x^2) using a sum of a series. 
I know term by term integration/differentiation, i tried substitution but it didnt work.Any ideas for how to approach the problem?

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2/469886#469886

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but i cant seem to understand how that post helps.

Comment: What's $f(x)$ here, then what should be $$f\left(\dfrac rn\right)$$

Comment: Hint: The primitive of the function is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}C(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}x)$. Where C is the Fresnel Integral, wich you need to evaluate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

Replace all of the $x$ with $x^2$, and then integrate term by term.