# How to evaluate this limit when variable tends to infinity?

Tags: limits

How to evaluate this limit when n tends to +infinity

$(1^4+2^4+...n^4)/n^5 - (1^3+2^3+...+n^3)/n^5$

I tried using L hopital but got answer zero which is incorrect, then I tried to somehow use some algebraic identity but couldn't figure out one.

Comment: Used the formalue for sum of cubes  and fourth powers?

Comment: shouldn't you get 1/5 by L'hopital?????

Comment: Is there some other method because The sum of fourth powers is little complex and will make it lengthy ?

Comment: @SakethMalyala how when we will take derivative in both cases above will be 4n^3 and 3n^2 smaller than below power hence zero.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2/469886#469886

Comment: Okay. Thanks can we do this purely by limits not by integration.

Comment: Last $n^5$ should read $n^4$?

Answer (score 1):

METHOD 1. (Long. No calculus): For integer $j$ let $S(n,j)=(1^j+...+n^j)$ and let $T(n,j)=S(n,j)/n^5.$ You are asking for $\lim_{n\to \infty}T(n,4)-T(n,3).$

(1)...  If $j\leq 3$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}T(n,j)=0.$ Proof: $$0<T(n,j)=(1^j+...+n^j)/n^5\leq (n^j+...+n^j)/n^5=(n\cdot n^j)/n^5\leq 1/n. $$

(2)... We have $(x+1)^5-x^5=5x^4+10x^3+10x^2+5x+1.$ Summing this from $x=1$ to $x=n $ we have $$ (i) \quad \sum_{x=1}^n(x+1)^5-x^5=5S(n,4)+10S(n,3)+10S(n,2)+5S(n,1)+S(n,0).$$ The LHS of $(i)$  is a telescoping sum, and is equal to $(n+1)^5-1.$ For example, when $n=3$ we have $(4^5-3^5)+(3^5-2^5)+(2^5-1^5)=4^5-1.$ So, dividing both sides of $(i)$ by $n^5$ we have $$ (ii)
 \quad \left(1+\frac {1}{n}\right)^5-n^{-5}=5T(n,4)+10T(n,3)+10T(n,2)+5T(n,1)+T(n,0).$$ The LHS of $(ii)$ tends to $1$ as $n\to  \infty.$  And we have seen that $T(n,j)\to 0$  as $n\to \infty$ when $j\in \{0,1,2,3\}$. Therefore $$1=\lim_{n\to \infty}5T(n,4).$$ $$ \text {Therefore  }\quad \lim_{n\to \infty}T(n,4)-T(n,3)=\lim_{n\to \infty}T(n,4)=1/5.$$

METHOD 2: Let $j\geq 0.$ The function $f(t)=t^j$ is increasing for $t>0.$ So for $x\geq 1$ we have      $$\int_{x-1}^x t^jdt\leq x^j\leq \int_x^{x+1}t^jdt.$$  Summing  this inequality from $x=1$ to $x=n$ gives $$ n^{j+1}/(j+1)= \int_0^nt^jdt\leq \;(1^j+...+n^j)\;\leq \int_1^{n+1}t^jdt=((n+1)^{j+1}-1)/(j+1).$$ And the rest is easy.