# Calculating limit to infinity with sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

my task is to calculate:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\sum _{i=1}^{n}\frac{25}{n^{2}}\sqrt{n^{2}-i^{2}}$$I take the constant out, so:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\frac{25}{n^{2}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{n^{2}-i^{2}}$$, but I have no idea how to set the boundries for integral, or Am I supposed to do something else?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Looks like a Riemann sum.

Comment: $\sqrt{n^2-i^2}=n\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2}$ gives you a Riemann sum.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, I know that it is, but  I should now set the intervals for integral, so should I put $$\sqrt{n^{2}-i^{2}}$$ =x?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2/469886#469886

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, so then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\sum _{i=1}^{n}\frac{25}{n^{2}}\sqrt{n^{2}-i^{2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\sum _{i=1}^{n}\frac{25}{n^{2}}n\sqrt{1-(\frac{i}{n})^{2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\frac{25}{n}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{1-(\frac{i}{n})^{2}}$$?

Comment: Yes, so the limit is $$25\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$$ @Peter And this is the area of a quarter circle of radius $1.$