# Why this limit calculation is wrong?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

why $$
\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\left( \frac{1}{n+1}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +\frac{1}{2n} \right) =\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{2n}=0
$$ is wrong?

Comment: This fails as the number of terms is not finite. We need to use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2

Comment: Isn't it obvious? The number of terms in the first limit is going to infinity. Suppose each term was $1/n$. Then their sum would always be 1, but each term would go to zero.

Comment: thank you very much.