# Problems with Integration

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2x-1)^2}\right)$$

My answer is 7/24, but the correct answer provided by the book is 1/2.

Could anyone help me?
Thanks for any insights.

Comment: How did you get 7/24?  Why not show your work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac1{(n+0)^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\frac1{(n+n-1)^2}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\frac1{(n+n)^2}\right)-\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac1{(2n)^2}-\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{1\le r\le n}\frac{n^2}{(n+r)^2}-0$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{1\le r\le n}\frac1{\left(1+\frac{r}n\right)^2}$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac1{(1+x)^2}dx$$

$$\text{as }\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Comment: Thanks. I eventually got the right answer by your help! ٩(｡・ω・｡)و

Comment: @user2967915, my pleasure. See also , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465075/find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits2n-r-1-fracr-sq and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469885/the-limit-of-a-sum

Comment: Nice solution lab bhattacharjee....

Comment: @juantheron, my pleasure