# A limit question involving summation $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \ln(\frac{n^2+(k-1)^2}{n^2+k^2})$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^{n} k  \ln\left(\frac{n^2+(k-1)^2}{n^2+k^2}\right)$$

Basically, First thought I had was to convert the limit into definite integral but couldn't do it.I don't have any other idea to solve it.

Thanks for any help in advanced.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), i.e. edit your post to elaborate your "First thought I had was to convert the limit into definite integral", include your attempts, and explain what stucked you. Hint: by [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), reduce to [this limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/928493/386889).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little help with a solution, try to complete the solution yourself, next time please write your attempt.

**Hint :**
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \ln(\frac{n^2+(k-1)^2}{n^2+k^2})＝\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \ln(n^2＋(k－1)^2)-k\ln(n^2＋k^2)\\~\\＝\ln(n^2)-\ln(n^2＋1)＋2\ln(n^2＋1)-2\ln(n^2＋4)＋3\ln(n^2＋4)-3\ln(n^2＋9)＋...＋n\ln(n^2＋(n－1)^2)-n\ln(n^2＋n^2)\\~\\＝\ln(n^2)＋\ln(n^2＋1)＋\ln(n^2＋4)＋...＋\ln(n^2＋(n－1)^2)-n\ln(2n^2)\\~\\＝-n\ln(2n^2)＋\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \ln(n^2＋k^2)$$

Answer (score 4):

Using
$$ \ln(1-x)=-x+O(x^2) $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\to \infty } \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^{n} k  \ln\left(\frac{n^2+(k-1)^2}{n^2+k^2}\right)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty }  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac kn \ln\left(1-\frac{2k-1}{n^2+k^2}\right)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty }  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac kn\left(-\frac{2k-1}{n^2+k^2}+O\bigg(\bigg(\frac{2k-1}{n^2+k^2}\bigg)^2\bigg)\right)\\
&=&-\lim_{n\to \infty }  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k(2k-1)}{n(n^2+k^2)}
\end{eqnarray}
which can be evaluated as $\frac\pi2-2$ by Mathematica. I don't know how to get this result by hand.

Comment: The summand is equivalently $-\frac1n \left(2-\frac{2n^2+k}{n^2+k^2}\right)$. I think the second term could be evaluated with the squeeze theorem with Riemann sums?

Comment: I tried this and didn’t get.

Comment: Now new question arises how to calculate this ?

Comment: Hey should I add this in the question description ?

Comment: You can ask this.