# Evaluation of a limit of a particular limit

Tags: calculus

How to find the value of this limit?
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\{(1+1/n)(1+2/n)\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(1+n/n)\}^{1/n}
$$

let $y=\{(1+1/n)(1+2/n)\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(1+n/n)\}^{1/n}$
Then using $\ln$ on both sides I have ultimately  reached the situation

$\ln y= 1/n\{\ln[(1+1/n)(1+2/n)\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot+1+n/n)]\}$. What to do next?

Comment: answer is e^(n*n+1/2)

Comment: See also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465075/find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits2n-r-1-fracr-sq

Comment: Sorry you are wrong answer is 4/e @user34304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\ln(ab)=\ln a+\ln b\implies\ln(\prod a_i)=\sum \ln a_i,$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

here $$\ln(y)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac rn\right)$$

Can you recognize $f(x)$ here?

Comment: i am getting $f(x)=ln(1+x)$ is it true?

Comment: @learnmore, Yes, now can you integrate?

Comment: Yes I have got the answer to be $4/e$