# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x(1/(n+x)+..+1/(n+nx))=\log(1+x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been wondering about the following problem for some time:

> Show that for any positive value of $n$,
> $$
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x\left({1\over n+x}+{1\over n+2x}+...+{1\over n+nx}\right)=\log(1+x)
> $$

[This is Example 15 of chapter one of *Methods of Mathematical Physics* by Jeffreys & Jeffreys, on page 55.]

One idea I had was that I could expand
$$
{1\over n+x}={1\over n}(1-x/n+(x/n)^2+...)
$$
but the sum of the various terms didn't lead to anything useful.

Adding successive terms in the form
$$
{1\over n+x}+{1\over n+2x} = {2n+3x\over (n+x)(n+2x)}
$$
etc. doesn't look promising. Any ideas?

Comment: Riemann Sum of $\dfrac{1}{1+t}$?

Comment: @QuangHoang - I believe you have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
x\,\Bigl(\frac{1}{n+x}+\frac{1}{n+x}+\dots+\frac{1}{n+n\,x}\Bigr)=\frac{x}{n}\,\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+x\,\frac{k}{n}}\to x\int_0^1\frac{dt}{1+x\,t}.
$$

Comment: The $t$ seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: $x$ is fixed. $t\sim k/n$$ is the integration variable.

Answer (score 2):

$$x\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{n+rx}=\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{\dfrac1x+\dfrac rn}$$

Now see [Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits^{2n}_{r =1} \frac{r}{\sqrt{n^2+r^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465075/find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits2n-r-1-fracr-sq/465081#465081)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> ${\ds{\tt\mbox{Besides the simple 'Riemann-Sum Method'}}}$:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{x\sum_{r\ =\ 1}^{n}{1 \over n + rx}}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{x\sum_{r\ =\ 1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n + rx - 1}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{%
x\int_{0}^{1}t^{n - 1}\sum_{r\ =\ 1}^{n}\pars{t^{x}}^{r}\,\dd t}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{%
x\int_{0}^{1}t^{n - 1}t^{x}\,{t^{nx} - 1 \over t^{x} - 1}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{%
x\int_{0}^{1}{t^{1 + \pars{n - 1}/x} - t^{n + 1 + \pars{n - 1}/x}\over 1 - t}\,
{1 \over x}\,t^{1/x - 1}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{n\pars{1 + 1/x}}\over 1 - t}\,\dd t
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{n/x}\over 1 - t}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\braces{%
\Psi\pars{n\bracks{1 + {1 \over x}} + 1}
-\Psi\pars{{n \over x} + 1}}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\braces{%
\ln\pars{n\bracks{x + 1} + x \over x} - \ln\pars{n + x \over x}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\ln\pars{n\bracks{x + 1} + x \over n + x}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{x + 1}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is something of a *tour de force*. For the benefit of others who had to look this up, here $\Psi$ is the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html).

Comment: @SuzuHirose Because the 'Riemann-Sum Method' was already here in the hands of ${\tt\mbox{@Julián Aguirre}}$ and ${\tt\mbox{@lab bhattacharjee}}$, I decided it will be useful to have a completely different answer. However, I still think that 'Riemman' is the best method.

Yes, $\Psi\left(\, z\,\right)$ is the [Digamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Thanks.