# Expressing limit of sum definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Evaluate limit by expressing it as a definite integral.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2n}\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2n}\right)+\cdots+\cos\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2n}\right)\right]$$

I do not know how to write this formula out first as a sum formula, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $cos(\frac\pi2)=0$ so you could formally incorporate in in the sum.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465075/find-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-limits2n-r-1-fracr-sq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

> $$\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2n}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$$

So

$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)+\cdots+\cos\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2n}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)+\cdots+\cos\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2n}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2n}\right)$$

And hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)$$

and then

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1\cos\left(\frac{x\pi}{2}\right)dx$$

Comment: So, if I properly understood, the result should be $1$. I think it could be $0$. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: This is precisely my problem ! I don't find anything wrong in your post. Since I had a doubt, I checked numerically. What if we write that $\cos\left(\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2n}\right)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2 n}\right)$ ?

Comment: Interesting, isn't it ? Cheers :-)