# $\lim_{n \to\infty}{\left(\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1^2}\right) + \left(\frac{n}{n^2+2^2} \right)+ \dots +\left(\frac{n}{n^2+n^2} \right)\right)}$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

> Find $$\lim_{n \to\infty}{\left(\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1^2}\right) + \left(\frac{n}{n^2+2^2} \right)+ \dots +\left(\frac{n}{n^2+n^2} \right)\right)}$$

Is there some sort of a theorem or a method behind this type of limits? I mean, I can't even begin to do the task, since I have no clue. 
Recent findings have shown that it might be related to Rieman's sums, yet again, this hardly makes the matters clear.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105719/evaluating-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-left-fracnn21-fracnn222?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Have you tried writing this as $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}\right)$$

Comment: the Limit should be $$\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the equation as $$S=\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sum_{r=1}^{n}{ \frac { n }{ { n }^{ 2 }+{ r }^{ 2 } }  }  } $$
$$S=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n } \sum _{ r=1 }^{ n  } \frac { 1 }{ 1+{ \left( \frac { r }{ n }  \right)  }^{ 2 } }  } $$
Converting Summation to Integration

$$S\quad =\quad \int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { 1 }{ 1+{ x }^{ 2 } }  } dx$$
$$S=\arctan { (1) } -\arctan { (0) } =\frac { \pi  }{ 4 } $$